# How do I measure for replacement screws?

Tags: screws

I'm attempting to replace some screws. The problem is, I don't have any existing to compare against a chart.

How can I measure the tapped length and diameter? Obviously, thread spacing is still a concern.

Comment: How are they used may give a small clue. What does it go through and what does it hold all together. and a picture too is always helpful.

Comment: What's it for? Many things these days have online parts diagrams and blowups. Maybe you can get the specs from the manufacturer?

Comment: You go to the hardware store and buy one of every screw that looks like it might be the right one.  Preferably from a place that sells then individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to my local hardware store and worked with the clerk to find the right screw. I was able to measure the millimeters in depth and I already knew it was a machine screw type.

We went through about 12 different screws until we found what we were looking for.

In case anyone was wondering, I was looking for mounting screws to fit the riser of my recurve bow.